# AAD B2C Custom Policy: How to Skip Claims provider selection for logins from multiple relaying party applications?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

**Setup:**

B2C is configured with 2 Claims Providers:
Azure AD using SAML and Auth0 with OIDC

Relying Party Applications: App1 using OIDC and App2 using SAML

Claims Provider TP for SessionManagement:
SM-SocialLogin (ExternalLoginSSOSessionProvider)

SAML2 Token Issuer TP for SessionManagement: SM-Saml-issuer (SamlSSOSessionProvider)

**Current State:**

I can login to the relaying party applications (app1 and app2) by selecting either ClaimsProvider individually on separate browser tabs.

When I use 2 separate User Journeys, with just one ClaimsProvider for App2, I can login directly using the session from App1 without the prompt for ClaimsProvider selection.

**My requirement:**

I need to be able to login to App1 by choosing either Claims Provider and then use the same session to login to App2. App2 shouldnt prompt for the ClaimsProvider.

Tried using PreConditions but unable to skip the claims provider selection screen for App2.

```
<Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
  <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
  <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
  <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
</Precondition>
```

Comment: My end goal is to login to App2 (dynamically without picking an IdP) using whichever Claims Provider I chose to login to App1. App2 should not prompt me to pick an IdP if I have a session through App1 already. Tried different preconditions and UserJourney options and unable to come up with a fix.


Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Resolved the issue by updating the UserJourneyBehaviors SingleSignOn "scope" within the RelyingParty files. Changed it from "Application" to "Tenant" which fixed the issue. Was expecting "Application" to work as I was using a single UseJourney policy, but the final orchestration step was different to support OIDC and SAML based apps.